# Launching Servie/Activity with Chrome/Default Internet Browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a newbie android developer, currently in the process of making a application similar to the concept of facebook chatheads. I want my service to start automatically whenever the user launches google chrome/ default internet browser. So whenever the user starts his internet browser, my service should also launch automatically. I have a basic idea about intents that can be used but not sure about the implementation. Is there any way to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no API to listen/capture other app's behaviors i.e launch or close . but you can do this by polling top most activity frequently using package manager API.

Comment: by getting recent tasks from activity manager you can identify the active foreground application. you have to do this frequently (say every sec) to know whether the chrome or native browser were launched. based on the result you can launch your service. note* this is a workaround.

Comment: http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/getting-info-about-your-currently-running-activities/

Comment: Umm. Is any event triggered or intent called when the user launches chrome which i can recieve in broadcastReciever()? That way the problem can be solved.